# monitoring voltage and amperage on Raspberry Pi USB ports

Tags: voltage, raspberry-pi, amperage, usb-device, usb-hub

**Question:**

*Is there a way to get the Pi to tell me the instantaneous voltage and amperage on the USB port that I could write to a data file?*

**Why I am trying to do this:**

I am trying to monitor rapidly changing Amperage and Voltage on my USB port of my Raspberry Pi 400, to understand what is happening when I am trying to poll all the devices on that port, and why not all of them are responding to the poll. I believe it might be power related, and if I can determine that, I might be able to find a way to spread the power demand, or provide auxiliary power to an underpowered USB device. This problem is described in more detail in a separate Stack Exchange post.

**Effort to date:**

I put a USB multimeter in stream on that port and I can see it change rapidly.  I am currently filming the changing display and then keying in the data to a spreadsheet for analysis and graphing.  But this is really tedious and error prone.

My meter doesn't record or log these changes, so I can't get it to provide me an automatic list,  but I know that using the gpiozero library I can get the pi to access the values of gpio pins and write them to a data file.

*Is there a way to get the Pi to tell me the instantaneous voltage and amperage on the USB ports itself that it could write to a data file?*

Answer (score 1):

While this is certainly doable from a theoretical point of view, and I certainly don’t want to discourage you from trying this as a fun project, it may be more hassle for you than simply (purchasing and) using an oscilloscope if you’re just wanting to root-cause your intermittent failures.

USB is a high-speed protocol. Depending on your devices, you may be looking at signal rates of 1.5, 12, 400, or 5000 Mbps. A data-synchronous power transition at anywhere near those speeds is far faster than a multimeter is able to keep up with, which is why your earlier attempt was showing fluctuation. And spurious, out-of-band current spikes on any misbehaving device in your topology could occur for arbitrarily brief periods. In both cases, your test tool needs to have a fast enough sample rate in order to not miss the offending event(s).

The tool that captures signals at high sample rates is an **oscilloscope**. Your proposed project can be reframed as, “a DIY oscilloscope that’s running on your DUT”. While clever and *potentially* cost-effective, you run three major risks in going this route:

1. Your acquisition engine may be too slow and/or jittery, causing you to miss your events.
2. The additional code, having to run at a high speed in order to maximize sample rate, can incur enough resource load to cause the behavior of the DUT to deviate so much from normal that it causes the issue to go away (or, of course, it might make the issue even more prominent instead, but the point is that it changes the behavior which you’re trying to observe and root-case).
3. If you aren’t careful with your probe hardware, you may inadvertently place excessive electrical load, again changing the behavior of your DUT.

(This is not to mention the potentially significant time you might need to invest in order to implement this correctly and with low enough resource utilization to make it practical, which, again, may be totally worthwhile to you for its own sake, but which is otherwise a distraction from your ultimate goal of USB stability.)

There are plenty of low-cost, used oscilloscopes out there that might have enough sample rate to catch your problem immediately. Alternatively, as a compromise between the DIY spirit and pragmatism, if you had a second Raspberry Pi you could consider building your own Pi-based oscilloscope (e.g, https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry+pi+oscilloscope). This way you can avoid loading the DUT while still having a relatively low-cost solution that you can also use for future projects.

However you acquire your scope, you’d simply set up one channel to record voltage, another channel to record voltage through a shunt to give you current, and set up a trigger to stop on voltage sag. (If you had additional channels available and the scope had enough bandwidth for the highest speed device in your topology, you could also record D+/D- traces and run them through a protocol decoder to try to see if there’s a correlation with certain packet patterns, but that’s significantly more involved and requires a lot more care.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. Use appropriate analog circuits to measure the voltage and current (a web search would be a good start) then use an I2C or SPI ADC to digitize the values. The rest, as they say, is just a matter of software.